# Looking for replacement LED

Tags: led, light, hardware

I'm looking for someone who can tell me what kind of LED this is
[image: LED]

(The barcode is: 5541475)

It's the blue LED from this projector: [Acer K135](http://www.acer.de/ac/de/DE/content/model/MR.JGM11.001)

I'm trying to modify the beamer and replace the LED with a white one. Therefor I need a replacement which has the same structural shape. Would be awesome if anyone has an answer or hint.

Comment: That has to be more than an LED because it has seven extra pins. Is it also some sort of sensor?

Comment: @PhilFrost Those multiple pins are for supporting high current: I see DLP illumination LEDs using 3 or 4 pins each for anode and cathode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest I could find is this one:
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PT-39-B-C21-EPD/1214-1000-ND/3431253

no doubt if that is in a product, there may be a new revision of that board since so many answers may cite very similar but not exact boards.

Comment: wow this looks really good - no clue how you found that.  thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like they make a white one, though.

Comment: White is not traditionally offered on a board like the one in the picture namely because White light isn't used in the same manner colored LEDs are.

EDIT: Okay nevermind.  They do make one sort of like the picture: http://luminus.com/products/CBT-90.html
It has two terminals rather than the multiple smaller connections.  Since I'm guessing the one in the picture uses just a Positive and Ground connections, identify which is which and you should be able to use this one as well.

Not my fault if you blow it up by hooking it up wrong.  Use a multimeter buddy.

Comment: No problem! Good luck.